# Cookie is not set / working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, cookies

i have a script with html login form jQuery and php all works fine but if visitor select remember me then cookie is not set or working even after i reload the page using jQuery window.location.replace('index.php'); still not working can any one please help, thanks

HTML

```
    <form class="login-form" action="" method="POST" name="operator_login">
    <div id="loginerror"></div>
    <div id="loginsuccess">Login Success!</div>    

     <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="adminusers_username"/>
     <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="adminusers_password"/>
     <input type="checkbox" name="operator_remember" checked /> Remember me
     <button type="submit"  name="operator_login">Login</button>            
    </form>
```

jQuery

```
    $(document).ready(function() {  
    $('.login-form').submit(function(){
        var adminusers_username = $('input[name=adminusers_username]'),
            adminusers_password = $('input[name=adminusers_password]'),
            loginerror = $('#loginerror'),
            loginsuccess = $('#loginsuccess');
                if ($('input[name=operator_remember]').is(':checked')) {
                    var operator_remember = 1;
                    }else{
                    var operator_remember = 2;
                 }
        $.post('server/login.php', {
        'adminusers_username': adminusers_username.val(), 
        'adminusers_password': adminusers_password.val(), 
        'operator_remember': operator_remember
        }, 
            function(data){
                if (data==1) {
                loginerror.hide();
                loginsuccess.show();
                window.location.replace('index.php');
                } else {
               loginerror.show().html(data);
            }
    });
    return false;
    }); 
});
```

PHP

```
session_start();
if ( isset($_REQUEST['adminusers_username']) 
    && $_REQUEST['adminusers_username'] !='' 
    &&  isset($_REQUEST['adminusers_password']) 
    && $_REQUEST['adminusers_password']!='') {

    $postedusername = $_REQUEST['adminusers_username'];
    $postedpassword = $_REQUEST['adminusers_password'];
    $rememberme = $_REQUEST['operator_remember'];

    $query_rsUserLogin = "SELECT * FROM adminusers 
    WHERE adminusers_username = '".trim($postedusername)."'";
    $rsUserLogin = mysql_query($query_rsUserLogin, $connection);
    $row_rsUserLogin = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsUserLogin);
    $totalRows_rsUserLogin = mysql_num_rows($rsUserLogin);

    $username = $row_rsUserLogin['adminusers_username'];
    $userpassword = $row_rsUserLogin['adminusers_password'];
    $email_conf = $row_rsUserLogin['admin_email_confirmed'];
    $user_status = $row_rsUserLogin['admin_status'];

    if ($totalRows_rsUserLogin > 0  ) { 
        if ($user_status == 'Active' ) {
            if ($email_conf == 'Yes' ) {
                if ($postedusername === $username 
                    && $postedpassword === $userpassword ){
                    if ($rememberme==1){
                        setcookie("adminusers_username", $username);
                        echo 1;
                        }else{
                        $_SESSION['adminusers_username'] = $username;
                        echo 1;
                    }
                }else {
                echo 'Password Incorrect!.';
                }
            }else{
            echo 'email not confirmed!.';
            }

        }else{
        echo 'acount closed!.';
        }
    }else {
    echo 'email not exist!.';
    }
}else {
echo 'insert Username and Password!.';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
&& $_REQUEST['adminusers_password']!=0) {
```

to

```
&& $_REQUEST['adminusers_password']!='') {
```

Comment: thanks for the hint, but i have already done that buy this is not the problem still i'm not having my cookie set !

Comment: well it does get set here. i copy&pasted your code and the only thing i had to correct was the `!=0` thingy. maybe you dont allow cookies in your browser?

Comment: yes if you use only the php code without jQuery it works,  but when it run through jQuey (POST) it doesn't!

Comment: nope, i said i copy&pasted your code. exact the same. it works. must be browser-related. the only thing i changed are the mysql-related things, i set the username and password to a fixed value. but the cookie gets set. try with a file test.php with content `<?php setcookie("adminusers_username", "admin"); ?>` and see if that cookie gets set.

Comment: i see now cookie set , thank you , only one thing when i close the browser and reopen , it ask again to login , maybe i need to set time for the cookie ?

Comment: YES adding time to Cookie Solve the problem, thank you very much :)